# Putting error messages under my table rows (style)

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I am making a review page for my app where its displays files that were uploaded. the problem I am having is....when a user uploads certain files that have errors in them, I display a warning message. I am able to display the messages but I want to display the messages below every file that was uploaded. Right now i have the files displaying in a table and the error messages come up but I'm not sure how to properly fix the error message below the file names.

html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="file in files">
     <td class="name-col">{{file.name}}</td>
     <td class="description">{{file.description}}</td>
     <td class="error-message">{{file.error_message}}</td>
</tr>
```

css:

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 8px;

    th {
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    td, td span {
      word-break: break-all;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the error messages in the same row in one of the columns, you can use @Adrianapolis's answer.

If you want the error messages in a new row, you can use the `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` directive:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="file in files">
    <td class="name-col">
        {{ file.name }}
    </td>
    <td class="description">
        {{ file.description }}
    </td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end
    ng-show="file.error_message">
    <td colspan="2" class="error-message">
        {{ file.error_message }}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Or if the `ng-repeat-end` will cause issues with the `ng-show` directive, you can always just repeat over a `tbody` element:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="file in files">
    <tr>
        <td class="name-col">{{file.name}}</td>
        <td class="description">{{file.description}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-if="file.error_message">
        <td class="error-message">{{file.error_message}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about putting the error message after the Message Digest instead of in a new column. Such as:

```
<tr ng-repeat="file in files">
     <td class="name-col">{{file.name}}</td>
     <td class="description">
         {{file.description}}
         {{file.error_message}}
     </td>
</tr>
```

Also I would assume the file.error_message is also returning an element container by the looks of it so just be sure it is a block type element so it renders on a new line.

Otherwise you may want to dynamically create a new row with a colspan of 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can display error message below name of file uploaded as below :

```
 <tr ng-repeat="file in files">
   <td class="name-col">{{file.name}}<br><span class="has-error">{{file.error_message}}</span></td>
   <td class="description">{{file.description}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Make use of bootstrap css class 'has-error' to display error message in red color(if you are using bootstrap)